# MQTT Broker Without internet

Tags: mqtt

How can I use a broker of MQTT like mosquitto, for example, without internet?

I've downloaded mosquitto, but I really don't know how to use it in my code.

I'm programming in python, so an answer in python is better for me to understand and use in my project.

Answer (score 1):

We can't really answer your question without knowing what you intend to actually do with MQTT.

What I will say is the following:

- A MQTT broker doesn't require "The Internet". They will (normally) require a TCP/IP network, but this can be as simple as just a TCP/IP stack on a single machine.
- The broker runs on it's own, you do not (again usually) embed the broker into your application, it is used so multiple applications can pass messages to each other.
- For working with any MQTT broker in Python there is the [Paho Python](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/) library. It's documentation includes examples to get you started.

I suggest you start the broker and then write a couple of test Python applications (one to subscribe to a topic and one to publish to that topic) to get a feel for how things work and if you get stuck you can ask a new question about a specific problem (explaining what you tried, what you expected it to do and how it didn't work).